# Maven Surefire @BeforeClass executing before every test

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to use the `@BeforeClass` annotation to initialize DB data and connection. But when I launch my test with `mvn test` I notice that the static method annotated by `@BeforeClass` is executed for each test.

I don't understand why the static method is not executed once for the test class?

My parent pom contain the following configuration for the maven surefire plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <properties.path>${properties.path}</properties.path>
            <dico.path>${dico.path}</dico.path>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <!-- On ne joue pas les tests d'integrations -->
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/**ITCase.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can your provide a short sample, and your configuration in your pom?